# Android application design help, How to control which activity shows

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-activity

Hello I require some advice on how to approach this problem,
bear with me as I am still new to android.

I have an activity that opens on application start and requires some information from the user, but next time the user opens the app, i want the application to open a different activity that will display the various information.
Kind of like facebooks app, where when you first run it, you have to login, and only then next time you run the app you are guided straight to the feed.

Any ideas how one could do this efficiently?

UPDATE: Ive stored the information via shared preferences and am now using a controller activity that decides which step to take.
So, Controller activity runs on start up, and decides whether to show a log in screen or whether to go straight to the information. But now im encountering a problem where i end up opening a blank activity (the controller) and then another ontop of that ( the decided activtiy). I dont want the blank activity to show, so its kinda of like a background process, any ideas?

Comment: Hello renno ,you can use Shared prefreneces whihch can store your information regarding Login name or email id or password , and will remain throughout the app even the appp crashes so you must find a way how to reuse   i mean when user logout remove all shared if preference if you want i will send you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have a main activity like a controller. Use a `SharedPreference` object to keep track of whether the user is logged in or not. So back in your main activity, read this value and if it is set go to your news feed activity else show a login screen activity. (as you do the check and redirection, you can show a progress dialog)

links for SharedPreferences

[MobTuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/)

[Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Hello silverback, thanks for the reply. Now this is what i was originally thinking, but, you see the Activity "Controller", how could i prevent this activity from ever showing? as i wouldnt want this activity to be shown and then the redirection activity shown?

Comment: You need to take the decision (which screen to show) somewhere right? Actually reading from the SharedPreference won't take much time. you can show a splash screen instead.

Comment: I understand that, but what im asking is if i implement a controller activity, how can i do so without it visually appearing.. atm when i have an activity that chooses whether to log in or display feed, it shows the blank activity first, and then decides, and opens the next activity, how do i prevent this?

Comment: Instead you can show some splash screen rather than a blank activity while you decide.

Comment: interesting, is there anyway i could remove/play around with the set content view?

Comment: I guess that can also be done, decide what to show and `setContentView` with the xml id accordingly. OfCourse your Activity's code will have to handle the situations of controls from both the pages.